# Convenience methods for Ruby's Number class and 0

Tags: ruby, numbers

I'm writing convenience methods to check if number is positive or negative like so:

```
class Numeric
  def positive?
    self > 0
  end

  def negative?
    self < 0
  end
end
```

but in this case I do not know how to handle cases like these:

```
>> 0.positive?
>> 0.negative?
```

**Update**: I've updated the typo in the class name. I used numeric because I needed to check the floats as well.

Comment: I find these methods quite unnecessary.  What's the advantage of using these over the very trivial comparisons?

Comment: @AboutRuby: Because something like `nums.select(&:positive?)` is much easier to grasp than the equivalent `nums.select(&0.method(:<))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the problem is that you're getting `false` for both, either you consider `0` to be positive or not. If so, you should have something like:

```
def positive?
    self >= 0
end
```

If not, leave it as it is, since `0` is neither positive not negative and you *should* return false for both.

However if the problem is that you're getting errors with `0.positive?` (far more likely), the reason you're getting a problem is because `0` is a `FixNum`, not a `Number`. You can see that with the following message:

```
testprog.rb:12: undefined method `positive?' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

You should probably add it to `Fixnum` itself, or `Integer`, or `Numeric`, the base class for various numeric types like `FixNum` and `BigNum`. Where you inject your convenience methods depends on how widely you want them available.

For example, if you change your code to the following (I'm including test code here):

```
class Numeric
    def positive?
        self > 0
    end

    def negative?
        self < 0
    end
end

print " 0 positive?: ",  0.positive?,"\n"
print " 0 negative?: ",  0.negative?,"\n"
print " 0 zero?    : ",  0.zero?,"\n\n"

print "99 positive?: ", 99.positive?,"\n"
print "99 negative?: ", 99.negative?,"\n"
print "99 zero?    : ", 99.zero?,"\n\n"

print "-2 positive?: ", -2.positive?,"\n"
print "-2 negative?: ", -2.negative?,"\n"
print "-2 zero?    : ", -2.zero?,"\n\n"
```

it then works fine, outputting:

```
 0 positive?: false
 0 negative?: false
 0 zero?    : true

99 positive?: true
99 negative?: false
99 zero?    : false

-2 positive?: false
-2 negative?: true
-2 zero?    : false
```

as expected.

Comment: I totally disagree.  Zero isn't a positive number, and any reasonable programmer who had to read/modify your code would probably assume that 0.positive? and 0.negative? would both return false.  After all, computer science is a branch of mathematics.

Comment: @Captain, most normal people are neither computer scientists nor mathematicians :-)

Comment: @banister: I use zero? myself, but is it for all versions of ruby, or only 1.8.7/1.9.1 or later?

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 2.3 [introduced `Numeric#positive?` and `Numeric#negative?`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3a48e12/numeric.c#L4196-L4197), if you are on Ruby 2.3+, should use these two instead.

Answer (score 0):

0 is a Fixnum, try:

```
p 0.class
```

> >> Fixnum

so, change class Number to class **Fixnum**

I dont know if you want to add this methods to floats/integers, but you could do something like this:

```
class Float
...your methods...
end

0.to_f.positive?
```

there are more possibilities to make this task, all depends on what type/class you want to add this methods