# Enumerable#find_all with exceptions Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find all of the amounts that are negative in an array excluding objects that are in certain categories. Here is a sample of the array.

```
@transactions =
  [{"amount"=>-20, "name"=>"DEPOSIT", "category"=>["BENEFITS"], "category_id"=>"21007000"},
   {"amount"=>-0.8, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>["Transfer", "Credit"], "category_id"=>"2106381"},
   {"amount"=>-20, "name"=>"DEPOSIT", "category"=>["Transfer", "Deposit"],
"category_id"=>"21007000"},
   {"amount"=>-1, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>["Transfer", "Credit"],
"category_id"=>"21005000"},
   {"amount"=>300.80, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>"Food", "category_id"=>"2106381"}]
```

So far I have something like this but the syntax is wrong and it does not work. i am not even sure I can use a "condition" on a find_all block.

```
items = @transactions.find_all ( { |t| t.fetch('amount') != t.fetch('amount').abs, :conditions => [ t.fetch('category_id') == '2106381' || t.fetch('category') == ["Benefits"] != ?, any? ]})
```

So find all the objects with a negative number for amount and exclude the objects from that list that have the following category id or category name.

With an output of only the objects that are negative and dont have the benefits name or category id "2106381"

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it is not right". [Edit] that information into your question.

Comment: Give us an array sample and then desired output.

Comment: I see a few problems. `find_all` takes a block, not an argument, so you want `find_all { ... }` not `findall (...)`. Also, your opening `{` is never closed. Are you able to run this code? If not, try to post a version that at least can run even if it doesn't do exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok I updated the code and added a sample array

Comment: You need a `{` before `"amount"=>300.80`. Always test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't especially clear, but I suspect this does what you want:

```
@transactions.select do |t|
  t["amount"] < 0 &&
    t["category_id"] != "2106381" &&
    t["category"] != "Benefits"
end
```

Alternatively, this is a bit more declarative (but slightly less efficient):

```
@transactions.select {|t| t["amount"] < 0 }
  .reject {|t| t["category_id"] == "2106381" || t["category"] == "Benefits" }
```

Comment: For some, it may read better without the negation and parenthesis and to have two `&&`s rather than one `&&` and one `||`: `t["amount"] < 0 && t["category_id"] != "2106381" && t["category"] != "Benefits"`. Your #2 may offend sensibilities because it requires two passes.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: `@transactions.select(&:negative?)` will only work for Ruby 2.3+, see: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3a48e12/numeric.c#L4196-L4197

Comment: @SoAwesomeMan `select(&:negative?)` didn't work anyway, for reasons that in hindsight should have been obvious. I've updated my answer. @CarySwoveland I tend to prefer affirmative expressions over negative ones, but in this case being able to drop the parentheses is a readability win, so .

Answer (score 2):

It's still a little unclear about what you're exactly trying to accomplish here, but based on what I understand you want to:

1) include all transactions with a negative `amount`
2) exclude all transaction with a specified `category_id`
3) exclude all transactions with a specefied `category`

To do this, you can do the following:

```
@transactions.find_all do |t|
  t['amount'] < 0 &&
  t['category_id'] != '2106381' &&
  t['category'] != ["BENEFITS"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below provides three different scenarios for `"amount"` and formats `"categories"` to downcase.

```
require 'pp' # require pretty_print

@transactions = [
  {"amount"=>-20, "name"=>"DEPOSIT", "category"=> ["BENEFITS"],"category_id"=>"21007000"},
  {"amount"=>-0.8, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>["Transfer", "Credit"], "category_id"=>"2106381"},
  {"amount"=>-20, "name"=>"DEPOSIT", "category"=>["Transfer", "Deposit"], "category_id"=>"21007000"},
  {"amount"=>-1, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>["Transfer", "Credit"], "category_id"=>"21005000"},
  {"amount"=>300.80, "name"=>"XFER", "category"=>"Food", "category_id"=>"2106381"}
]

# Enumerable#find_all
# see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all
items = @transactions.find_all do |t|

  # 1) amount is less than zero
  t.fetch('amount') < 0 && 

  # 2) amount is less than zero or zero
  #t.fetch('amount') <= 0 && 

  # 3) Ruby 2.3 use core method: Numeric#negative?
  # see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-negative-3F
  # see: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3a48e12/numeric.c#L4196-L4197
  # via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34146626
  #t.fetch('amount').negative? &&

  t.fetch('category_id') != '2106381' &&

  # category is array so map and downcase before Array#include?
  # see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-map
  # see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F
  !(t.fetch('category').map {|c| c.downcase}.include?("benefits"))
end

pp items
# [{"amount"=>-20,
#  "name"=>"DEPOSIT",
#  "category"=>["Transfer", "Deposit"],
#  "category_id"=>"21007000"},
# {"amount"=>-1,
#  "name"=>"XFER",
#  "category"=>["Transfer", "Credit"],
#  "category_id"=>"21005000"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
negative_transactions = @transactions.find_all do |trans| 
  trans["amount"] < 0 && (trans["category"] != ["BENEFITS"] && trans["category_id"] != "2106381")
end

puts negative_transactions
```

Comment: I believe `||` should be `&&`. The OP's penultimate paragraph is quite clear.